# Tag editor component for Delphi/C++Builder

Tags: delphi, components, c++builder, vcl

I need a VCL tag editor component for Delphi or C++Builder, similar to what's available for JavaScript: e.g. [this one](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/examples.html), or [this one](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) or StackOverflow's own tags editor.

Is there something like this available or do I need to make it from scratch?

Some specific things that I need are:

- Editor should allow either scrolling or become multi-line if more tags are present than the editor's width allows. If multi-line, there should be an option to define some maximum height however, preventing it from becoming too tall
- Option to select whether tags are created when pressing space or comma key
- Prompt text in the editor, when it is not focused (for example "Add new tag")
- Ideally, you should be able to move between tags (highlighting them) using the keyboard arrows, so you can delete any tag using the keyboard only

Comment: Maybe you can tweak [TagCloud for VCL](http://www.be-precision.com/products/tagcloud/) to do what you want. "Easy tag items definition, both in design-time and run-time" reads promising.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Of course you want to do this yourself! Writing GUI controls is fun and rewarding!

You could do something like

```
unit TagEditor;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, Forms, Graphics,
  Types, Menus;

type
  TClickInfo = cardinal;
  GetTagIndex = word;

const TAG_LOW = 0;
const TAG_HIGH = MAXWORD - 2;
const EDITOR = MAXWORD - 1;
const NOWHERE = MAXWORD;

const PART_BODY = $00000000;
const PART_REMOVE_BUTTON = $00010000;

function GetTagPart(ClickInfo: TClickInfo): cardinal;

type
  TTagClickEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; TagIndex: integer;
    const TagCaption: string) of object;
  TRemoveConfirmEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; TagIndex: integer;
    const TagCaption: string; var CanRemove: boolean) of object;
  TTagEditor = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FTags: TStringList;
    FEdit: TEdit;
    FBgColor: TColor;
    FBorderColor: TColor;
    FTagBgColor: TColor;
    FTagBorderColor: TColor;
    FSpacing: integer;
    FTextColor: TColor;
    FLefts, FRights, FWidths,
    FTops, FBottoms: array of integer;
    FCloseBtnLefts, FCloseBtnTops: array of integer;
    FCloseBtnWidth: integer;
    FSpaceAccepts: boolean;
    FCommaAccepts: boolean;
    FSemicolonAccepts: boolean;
    FTrimInput: boolean;
    FNoLeadingSpaceInput: boolean;
    FTagClickEvent: TTagClickEvent;
    FAllowDuplicates: boolean;
    FPopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
    FMultiLine: boolean;
    FTagHeight: integer;
    FEditPos: TPoint;
    FActualTagHeight: integer;
    FShrunk: boolean;
    FEditorColor: TColor;
    FTagAdded: TNotifyEvent;
    FTagRemoved: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnRemoveConfirm: TRemoveConfirmEvent;
    FMouseDownClickInfo: TClickInfo;
    FCaretVisible: boolean;
    FDragging: boolean;
    FAutoHeight: boolean;
    FNumRows: integer;
    procedure SetBorderColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetTagBgColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetTagBorderColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure SetSpacing(const Value: integer);
    procedure TagChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetTags(const Value: TStringList);
    procedure SetTextColor(const Value: TColor);
    procedure ShowEditor;
    procedure HideEditor;
    procedure EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure mnuDeleteItemClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetMultiLine(const Value: boolean);
    procedure SetTagHeight(const Value: integer);
    procedure EditExit(Sender: TObject);
    function Accept: boolean;
    procedure SetBgColor(const Value: TColor);
    function GetClickInfoAt(X, Y: integer): TClickInfo;
    function GetSeparatorIndexAt(X, Y: integer): integer;
    procedure CreateCaret;
    procedure DestroyCaret;
    function IsFirstOnRow(TagIndex: integer): boolean; inline;
    function IsLastOnRow(TagIndex: integer): boolean;
    procedure SetAutoHeight(const Value: boolean);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer;
      Y: Integer); override;
    procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); override;

    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer;
      Y: Integer); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property TabOrder;
    property TabStop;
    property Color;
    property Anchors;
    property Align;
    property Tag;
    property Cursor;
    property BgColor: TColor read FBgColor write SetBgColor;
    property BorderColor: TColor read FBorderColor write SetBorderColor;
    property TagBgColor: TColor read FTagBgColor write SetTagBgColor;
    property TagBorderColor: TColor read FTagBorderColor
      write SetTagBorderColor;
    property Spacing: integer read FSpacing write SetSpacing;
    property Tags: TStringList read FTags write SetTags;
    property TextColor: TColor read FTextColor write SetTextColor;
    property SpaceAccepts: boolean read FSpaceAccepts write FSpaceAccepts
      default true;
    property CommaAccepts: boolean read FCommaAccepts write FCommaAccepts
      default true;
    property SemicolonAccepts: boolean read FSemicolonAccepts
      write FSemicolonAccepts default true;
    property TrimInput: boolean read FTrimInput write FTrimInput default true;
    property NoLeadingSpaceInput: boolean read FNoLeadingSpaceInput
      write FNoLeadingSpaceInput default true;
    property AllowDuplicates: boolean read FAllowDuplicates write FAllowDuplicates
      default false;
    property MultiLine: boolean read FMultiLine write SetMultiLine default false;
    property TagHeight: integer read FTagHeight write SetTagHeight default 32;
    property EditorColor: TColor read FEditorColor write FEditorColor
      default clWindow;
    property AutoHeight: boolean read FAutoHeight write SetAutoHeight;
    property OnTagClick: TTagClickEvent read FTagClickEvent write FTagClickEvent;
    property OnTagAdded: TNotifyEvent read FTagAdded write FTagAdded;
    property OnTagRemoved: TNotifyEvent read FTagRemoved write FTagRemoved;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
    property OnRemoveConfirm: TRemoveConfirmEvent read FOnRemoveConfirm
      write FOnRemoveConfirm;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses Math, Clipbrd;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Rejbrand 2009', [TTagEditor]);
end;

function IsKeyDown(const VK: integer): boolean;
begin
  IsKeyDown := GetKeyState(VK) and $8000 <> 0;
end;

function GetTagPart(ClickInfo: TClickInfo): cardinal;
begin
  result := ClickInfo and $FFFF0000;
end;

{ TTagEditor }

constructor TTagEditor.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  mnuItem: TMenuItem;
begin
  inherited;
  FEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FEdit.Parent := Self;
  FEdit.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  FEdit.Visible := false;
  FEdit.OnKeyPress := EditKeyPress;
  FEdit.OnExit := EditExit;

  FTags := TStringList.Create;
  FTags.OnChange := TagChange;

  FBgColor := clWindow;
  FBorderColor := clWindowFrame;
  FTagBgColor := clSkyBlue;
  FTagBorderColor := clNavy;
  FSpacing := 8;
  FTextColor := clWhite;
  FSpaceAccepts := true;
  FCommaAccepts := true;
  FSemicolonAccepts := true;
  FTrimInput := true;
  FNoLeadingSpaceInput := true;
  FAllowDuplicates := false;
  FMultiLine := false;
  FTagHeight := 32;
  FShrunk := false;
  FEditorColor := clWindow;
  FCaretVisible := false;
  FDragging := false;

  FPopupMenu := TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
  mnuItem := TMenuItem.Create(PopupMenu);
  mnuItem.Caption := 'Delete';
  mnuItem.OnClick := mnuDeleteItemClick;
  mnuItem.Hint := 'Deletes the selected tag.';
  FPopupMenu.Items.Add(mnuItem);

  TabStop := true;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.EditExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FEdit.Text <> '' then
    Accept
  else
    HideEditor;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.mnuDeleteItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender is TMenuItem then
  begin
    FTags.Delete(TMenuItem(Sender).Tag);
    if Assigned(FTagRemoved) then
      FTagRemoved(Self);
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.TagChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Invalidate;
  if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TTagEditor.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_SETFOCUS:
      Invalidate;
    WM_KILLFOCUS:
      begin
        if FCaretVisible then DestroyCaret;
        FDragging := false;
        Invalidate;
      end;
    WM_COPY:
      Clipboard.AsText := FTags.DelimitedText;
    WM_CLEAR:
      FTags.Clear;
    WM_CUT:
      begin
        Clipboard.AsText := FTags.DelimitedText;
        FTags.Clear;
      end;
    WM_PASTE:
      begin
        if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then
          if FTags.Count = 0 then
            FTags.DelimitedText := Clipboard.AsText
          else
            FTags.DelimitedText := FTags.DelimitedText + ',' + Clipboard.AsText;
      end;
  end;
end;

function TTagEditor.Accept: boolean;
begin
  Assert(FEdit.Visible);
  result := false;
  if FTrimInput then
    FEdit.Text := Trim(FEdit.Text);
  if (FEdit.Text = '') or
    ((not AllowDuplicates) and (FTags.IndexOf(FEdit.Text) <> -1))  then
  begin
    beep;
    Exit;
  end;
  FTags.Add(FEdit.Text);
  result := true;
  HideEditor;
  if Assigned(FTagAdded) then
    FTagAdded(Self);
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin

  if (Key = chr(VK_SPACE)) and (FEdit.Text = '') and FNoLeadingSpaceInput then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    Exit;
  end;

  if ((Key = chr(VK_SPACE)) and FSpaceAccepts) or
    ((Key = ',') and FCommaAccepts) or
    ((Key = ';') and FSemicolonAccepts) then
    Key := chr(VK_RETURN);

  case ord(Key) of
    VK_RETURN:
      begin
        Accept;
        ShowEditor;
        Key := #0;
      end;
    VK_BACK:
      begin
        if (FEdit.Text = '') and (FTags.Count > 0) then
        begin
          FTags.Delete(FTags.Count - 1);
          if Assigned(FTagRemoved) then
            FTagRemoved(Sender);
        end;
      end;
    VK_ESCAPE:
      begin
        HideEditor;
        Self.SetFocus;
        Key := #0;
      end;
  end;

end;

destructor TTagEditor.Destroy;
begin
  FPopupMenu.Free;
  FTags.Free;
  FEdit.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.HideEditor;
begin
  FEdit.Text := '';
  FEdit.Hide;
//  SetFocus;
end;


procedure TTagEditor.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;
  case Key of
    VK_END:
      ShowEditor;
    VK_DELETE:
      Perform(WM_CLEAR, 0, 0);
    VK_INSERT:
      Perform(WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
begin
  inherited;

  case Key of
    ^C:
      begin
        Perform(WM_COPY, 0, 0);
        Key := #0;
        Exit;
      end;
    ^X:
      begin
        Perform(WM_CUT, 0, 0);
        Key := #0;
        Exit;
      end;
    ^V:
      begin
        Perform(WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
        Key := #0;
        Exit;
      end;
  end;

  ShowEditor;
  FEdit.Perform(WM_CHAR, ord(Key), 0);
end;

function TTagEditor.GetClickInfoAt(X, Y: integer): TClickInfo;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := NOWHERE;
  if (X >= FEditPos.X) and (Y >= FEditPos.Y) then
    Exit(EDITOR);

  for i := 0 to FTags.Count - 1 do
    if InRange(X, FLefts[i], FRights[i]) and InRange(Y, FTops[i], FBottoms[i]) then
    begin
      result := i;
      if InRange(X, FCloseBtnLefts[i], FCloseBtnLefts[i] + FCloseBtnWidth) and
        InRange(Y, FCloseBtnTops[i], FCloseBtnTops[i] + FActualTagHeight) and
        not FShrunk then
        result := result or PART_REMOVE_BUTTON;
      break;
    end;
end;

function TTagEditor.IsFirstOnRow(TagIndex: integer): boolean;
begin
  result := (TagIndex = 0) or (FTops[TagIndex] > FTops[TagIndex-1]);
end;

function TTagEditor.IsLastOnRow(TagIndex: integer): boolean;
begin
  result := (TagIndex = FTags.Count - 1) or (FTops[TagIndex] < FTops[TagIndex+1]);
end;

function TTagEditor.GetSeparatorIndexAt(X, Y: integer): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := FTags.Count;
  Y := Max(Y, FSpacing + 1);
  for i := FTags.Count - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    if Y < FTops[i] then Continue;
    if (IsLastOnRow(i) and (X >= FRights[i])) or
      ((X < FRights[i]) and (IsFirstOnRow(i) or (FRights[i-1] < X))) then
    begin
      result := i;
      if (IsLastOnRow(i) and (X >= FRights[i])) then inc(result);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  FMouseDownClickInfo := GetClickInfoAt(X, Y);
  if GetTagIndex(FMouseDownClickInfo) <> EDITOR then
    SetFocus;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.CreateCaret;
begin
  if not FCaretVisible then
    FCaretVisible := Windows.CreateCaret(Handle, 0, 0, FActualTagHeight);
end;

procedure TTagEditor.DestroyCaret;
begin
  if not FCaretVisible then Exit;
  Windows.DestroyCaret;
  FCaretVisible := false;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  SepIndex: integer;
begin
  inherited;

  if IsKeyDown(VK_LBUTTON) and
    InRange(GetTagIndex(FMouseDownClickInfo), TAG_LOW, TAG_HIGH) then
  begin
    FDragging := true;
    Screen.Cursor := crDrag;
    SepIndex := GetSeparatorIndexAt(X, Y);
    TForm(Parent).Caption := IntToStr(SepIndex);
    CreateCaret;
    if SepIndex = FTags.Count then
      SetCaretPos(FLefts[SepIndex - 1] + FWidths[SepIndex - 1] + FSpacing div 2,
        FTops[SepIndex - 1])
    else
      SetCaretPos(FLefts[SepIndex] - FSpacing div 2, FTops[SepIndex]);
    ShowCaret(Handle);
    Exit;
  end;

  case GetTagIndex(GetClickInfoAt(X,Y)) of
    NOWHERE: Cursor := crArrow;
    EDITOR: Cursor := crIBeam;
    TAG_LOW..TAG_HIGH: Cursor := crHandPoint;
  end;

end;

procedure TTagEditor.MouseUp(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  pnt: TPoint;
  CanRemove: boolean;
  ClickInfo: TClickInfo;
  i: word;
  p: cardinal;
  SepIndex: integer;
begin
  inherited;

  if FDragging then
  begin
    DestroyCaret;
    FDragging := false;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    SepIndex := GetSeparatorIndexAt(X, Y);
    if not InRange(SepIndex, GetTagIndex(FMouseDownClickInfo),
      GetTagIndex(FMouseDownClickInfo) + 1) then
      FTags.Move(GetTagIndex(FMouseDownClickInfo), SepIndex -
        IfThen(SepIndex > GetTagIndex(FMouseDownClickInfo), 1, 0));
    Exit;
  end;

  ClickInfo := GetClickInfoAt(X, Y);

  if ClickInfo <> FMouseDownClickInfo then Exit;

  i := GetTagIndex(ClickInfo);
  p := GetTagPart(ClickInfo);

  case i of
    EDITOR:
      ShowEditor;
    NOWHERE: ;
  else
    case Button of
      mbLeft:
        begin
          case p of
            PART_BODY:
              if Assigned(FTagClickEvent) then
                FTagClickEvent(Self, i, FTags[i]);
            PART_REMOVE_BUTTON:
              begin
                if Assigned(FOnRemoveConfirm) then
                begin
                  CanRemove := false;
                  FOnRemoveConfirm(Self, i, FTags[i], CanRemove);
                  if not CanRemove then Exit;
                end;
                FTags.Delete(i);
                if Assigned(FTagRemoved) then
                  FTagRemoved(Self);
              end;
          end;
        end;
      mbRight:
        begin
          FPopupMenu.Items[0].Tag := i;
          pnt := ClientToScreen(Point(X,Y));
          FPopupMenu.Items[0].Caption := 'Delete tag "' + FTags[i] + '"';
          FPopupMenu.Popup(pnt.X, pnt.Y);
        end;
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure TTagEditor.Paint;
var
  i: integer;
  w: integer;
  x, y: integer;
  R: TRect;
  MeanWidth: integer;
  S: string;
  DesiredHeight: integer;
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := FBgColor;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := FBorderColor;
  Canvas.Rectangle(ClientRect);
  Canvas.Font.Assign(Self.Font);
  SetLength(FLefts, FTags.Count);
  SetLength(FRights, FTags.Count);
  SetLength(FTops, FTags.Count);
  SetLength(FBottoms, FTags.Count);
  SetLength(FWidths, FTags.Count);
  SetLength(FCloseBtnLefts, FTags.Count);
  SetLength(FCloseBtnTops, FTags.Count);
  FCloseBtnWidth := Canvas.TextWidth('×');
  FShrunk := false;

  // Do metrics
  FNumRows := 1;
  if FMultiLine then
  begin
    FActualTagHeight := FTagHeight;
    x := FSpacing;
    y := FSpacing;
    for i := 0 to FTags.Count - 1 do
    begin
      FWidths[i] := Canvas.TextWidth(FTags[i] + ' ×') + 2*FSpacing;
      FLefts[i] := x;
      FRights[i] := x + FWidths[i];
      FTops[i] := y;
      FBottoms[i] := y + FTagHeight;

      if x + FWidths[i] + FSpacing > ClientWidth then
   { no need to make room for the editor, since it can reside on the next row! }
      begin
        x := FSpacing;
        inc(y, FTagHeight + FSpacing);
        inc(FNumRows);
        FLefts[i] := x;
        FRights[i] := x + FWidths[i];
        FTops[i] := y;
        FBottoms[i] := y + FTagHeight;
      end;

      FCloseBtnLefts[i] := x + FWidths[i] - FCloseBtnWidth - FSpacing;
      FCloseBtnTops[i] := y;

      inc(x, FWidths[i] + FSpacing);
    end;
  end
  else // i.e., not FMultiLine
  begin
    FActualTagHeight := ClientHeight - 2*FSpacing;
    x := FSpacing;
    y := FSpacing;
    for i := 0 to FTags.Count - 1 do
    begin
      FWidths[i] := Canvas.TextWidth(FTags[i] + ' ×') + 2*FSpacing;
      FLefts[i] := x;
      FRights[i] := x + FWidths[i];
      FTops[i] := y;
      FBottoms[i] := y + FActualTagHeight;
      inc(x, FWidths[i] + FSpacing);
      FCloseBtnLefts[i] := FRights[i] - FCloseBtnWidth - FSpacing;
      FCloseBtnTops[i] := y;
    end;
    FShrunk := x + 64 {FEdit} > ClientWidth;
    if FShrunk then
    begin

      // Enough to remove close buttons?
      x := FSpacing;
      y := FSpacing;
      for i := 0 to FTags.Count - 1 do
      begin
        FWidths[i] := Canvas.TextWidth(FTags[i]) + 2*FSpacing;
        FLefts[i] := x;
        FRights[i] := x + FWidths[i];
        FTops[i] := y;
        FBottoms[i] := y + FActualTagHeight;
        inc(x, FWidths[i] + FSpacing);
        FCloseBtnLefts[i] := FRights[i] - FCloseBtnWidth - FSpacing;
        FCloseBtnTops[i] := y;
      end;

      if x + 64 {FEdit} > ClientWidth then // apparently no
      begin
        MeanWidth := (ClientWidth - 2*FSpacing - 64 {FEdit}) div FTags.Count - FSpacing;
        x := FSpacing;
        for i := 0 to FTags.Count - 1 do
        begin
          FWidths[i] := Min(FWidths[i], MeanWidth);
          FLefts[i] := x;
          FRights[i] := x  + FWidths[i];
          inc(x, FWidths[i] + FSpacing);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  FEditPos := Point(FSpacing, FSpacing + (FActualTagHeight - FEdit.Height) div 2);
  if FTags.Count > 0 then
    FEditPos := Point(FRights[FTags.Count - 1] + FSpacing,
      FTops[FTags.Count - 1] + (FActualTagHeight - FEdit.Height) div 2);
  if FMultiLine and (FEditPos.X + 64 > ClientWidth) and (FTags.Count > 0) then
  begin
    FEditPos := Point(FSpacing,
      FTops[FTags.Count - 1] + FTagHeight + FSpacing +
      (FActualTagHeight - FEdit.Height) div 2);
    inc(FNumRows);
  end;

  DesiredHeight := FSpacing + FNumRows*(FTagHeight+FSpacing);
  if FMultiLine and FAutoHeight and (ClientHeight <> DesiredHeight) then
  begin
    ClientHeight := DesiredHeight;
    Invalidate;
    Exit;
  end;

  // Draw
  for i := 0 to FTags.Count - 1 do
  begin
    x := FLefts[i];
    y := FTops[i];
    w := FWidths[i];
    R := Rect(x, y, x + w, y + FActualTagHeight);
    Canvas.Brush.Color := FTagBgColor;
    Canvas.Pen.Color := FTagBorderColor;
    Canvas.Rectangle(R);
    Canvas.Font.Color := FTextColor;
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    R.Left := R.Left + FSpacing;
    S := FTags[i];
    if not FShrunk then
      S := S + ' ×';
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), -1, R, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or
      DT_LEFT or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_NOPREFIX);
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  end;

  if FEdit.Visible then
  begin
    FEdit.Left := FEditPos.X;
    FEdit.Top := FEditPos.Y;
    FEdit.Width := ClientWidth - FEdit.Left - FSpacing;
  end;
  if Focused then
  begin
    R := Rect(2, 2, ClientWidth - 2, ClientHeight - 2);
    SetBkColor(Canvas.Handle, clWhite);
    SetTextColor(clBlack);
    Canvas.DrawFocusRect(R);
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetAutoHeight(const Value: boolean);
begin
  if FAutoHeight <> Value then
  begin
    FAutoHeight := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetBgColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  if FBgColor <> Value then
  begin
    FBgColor := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetBorderColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  if FBorderColor <> Value then
  begin
    FBorderColor := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetMultiLine(const Value: boolean);
begin
  if FMultiLine <> Value then
  begin
    FMultiLine := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetTagBgColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  if FTagBgColor <> Value then
  begin
    FTagBgColor := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetTagBorderColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  if FTagBorderColor <> Value then
  begin
    FTagBorderColor := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetTagHeight(const Value: integer);
begin
  if FTagHeight <> Value then
  begin
    FTagHeight := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetTags(const Value: TStringList);
begin
  FTags.Assign(Value);
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetTextColor(const Value: TColor);
begin
  if FTextColor <> Value then
  begin
    FTextColor := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.ShowEditor;
begin
  FEdit.Left := FEditPos.X;
  FEdit.Top := FEditPos.Y;
  FEdit.Width := ClientWidth - FEdit.Left - FSpacing;
  FEdit.Color := FEditorColor;
  FEdit.Text := '';
  FEdit.Show;
  FEdit.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TTagEditor.SetSpacing(const Value: integer);
begin
  if FSpacing <> Value then
  begin
    FSpacing := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

initialization
  Screen.Cursors[crHandPoint] := LoadCursor(0, IDC_HAND); // Get the normal hand cursor

end.
```

which yields

[image: Screenshot]

[Sample video](https://privat.rejbrand.se/tageditor.mp4)

[Demo (Compiled EXE)](https://privat.rejbrand.se/tagEditorTest.exe)

If I get more time later on today I will do some more work on this control, e.g., button highlighting on mouse hover, tag click event, button max width etc.

**Update:** Added a lot of features.

**Update:** Added multi-line feature.

**Update:** More features.

**Update:** Added clipboard interface, fixed some issues, etc.

**Update:** Added drag-and-drop reordering and fixed some minor issues. By the way, this is the last version I'll post here. Later versions (if there will be any) will be posted at http://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/controls/.

**Update:** Added `AutoHeight` property, made edit box vertically centred, and changed the drag cursor. (Yeah, I couldn't resist making yet another update.)

Comment: Could you add a link to downloadable pas file? It's a PITA to get the code from SO into the Delphi editor. ;-)

Comment: That's excellent! I will use it as a base for my work. Thank you very much! I am not very good with Delphi, but if I manage to improve the component, I will update your answer.

Comment: I will try to make it multi-line if there are too many tags, because with the shrinking tags size, it does not look good enough.

Comment: @riot_starter: I agree multi-line should be added. I probably will get time to add that today.

Comment: @riot_starter: I added a multiline feature. I have to go to work now, but when I get back I will polish the code a bit more.

Comment: @Andreas, that is exactly what I was looking for. I will wait for your update later today.

Comment: Added a lot of polish. Please tell me if there is a bug left. (For some strange reason, the `DrawFocusRect` draws a *solid* rectangle if `DrawText` is used immediately before it. I don't know why. David: Do you know why?)

Comment: Not a bug but a feature I think is missing is editing of existing tags (like in SO). (Not to mention drag and drop rearranging :-))

Comment: Uli: I completely agree. Perhaps I get some time over to implement that.

Comment: BTW: They seem to have broken the rendering of edited tags in SO while you were implementing your Delphi equivalent. :-)

Comment: @Andreas: Great work, BTW. Since I tested your first version I'm looking for a use case.

Comment: @Andreas I believe the solid rect is drawn when the difference (in luminance) between the brush color (`SetBkColor`) and the font's (`SetTextColor`) is too little, as judged by Windows. I allways (temporarilly) reset it to black-white (in either way) before using `DrawFocusRect`.

Comment: @NGLN: Oh, that indeed resolves the issue. Thank you! Is it just me or does this feel like a 'bugoid' in GDI?

Comment: @Andreas I don't dare to answer that. It's kind of logic behaviour in case the colors are matchy. I think it's a usability issue.

Comment: @NGLN: I see. At least it would be helpful if it was [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162479(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much, again! I have one more question: if I want to make the control automatically increase its height, if there are multi-line tags, what is the best approach to do it?

Comment: @riot_starter: I have also thought of that. I am considering adding a `AutoSize` (or `AutoHeight`) property. But right now I am working on drag-and-drop reordering of tags.

Comment: The first one I am aware of, but it is not entirely straight-forward to solve, because of how Windows EDIT controls work... There is a TagHeight property (but it only works in multi-line mode, beucase in single-line mode the height is adjusted to the control's size).

Comment: @riot_starter: I added drag-and-drop reordering. I might implement `AutoHeight` later tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Now I added the `AutoHeight` property and made the edit box vertically centred.

Comment: Awesome! You should definitely publish it somewhere, it's worth it :)

Comment: One minor bug: If you leave TextColor at its default value white, start typing a new tag and press Escape the TextColor is set to black.

Comment: I was playing around with the component and have found one limitation, which however maybe to too complex to fix. If there are too many tags, AutoHeight is working fine until it gets taller than the form it is placed on. Then you no longer see all the tags. The same thing happens if you have AutoHeight turned off and enter too many tags too. From a UX point of view, vertical scrollbar will be the best to remedy the situation (working with conjunction of MaxHeight when AutoHeight is turned on). However, I suspect that is not as easy to code.

Comment: @riot_starter: It sure can be done. I have done similar things quite a few times before. But it takes some effort. Perhaps I will find some time to do it.

Comment: I have added scrollbar support and fixed a few issues. Unfortunately, however, I cannot publish the new version here, because StackOverflow won't let me publish that many characters in a single post. So you have to go to http://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/controls/tageditor/.