# Tag Editor component for Delphi, but with a list of possible value

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

I found a part of my question in older questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12600297/6374639 - thanks to Andreas Rejbrand.
[image: screenshot]

But, how can I add the ability to have a list of choices when I entered text as in the recipient list in Outlook , for example?

Comment: Are you wanting something aside from a combobox control that contains a list of choices in the Items property?  If so, please describe in more detail the UI behavior that you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: You could try to use Andreas' component and intercept MouseDown. Show a inplace combobox with autocomplete.